# Property of analytic function on upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that F is analytic in $\{z|Im(z)>0\}$, continuous in $\{z|Im(z)\geq 0\}$ and bounded in each half plane $\{z|Im(z)\geq h>0\}$ and satisfies
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\log(|F(x+i)|)}{1+x^2}dx=-\infty. $$
How to show that $F(z)=0,$ for $Im(z)>0? $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this could be approached is to first let $G(z)=F(z+i), \Im z \ge -1$ so $G$ is analytic and bounded on $\{z|Im(z)\geq -1\}$ and let $f(w)=G(\frac{w+1}{i(1-w)}), |w|<1$
Then $f$ is analytic in the open unit disc, continuous and bounded on the unit circle except possibly at $1$ where it has bounded non-tangential limits, so $f \in H^{\infty}(\mathbb D)$

Since $dx/(x^2+1)=-2d\theta, \infty \to 1=e^{i0}, 0 \to -1=e^{i\pi}$, we have:

$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\log(|F(x+i)|)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\log(|G(x)|)}{1+x^2}dx=2\int_0^{\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$

so we need to prove that if $f \in H^{\infty}(\mathbb D)$ and $\int_0^{\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta=-\infty$, $f$ is identically zero.

This result is classic and holds with $[0,\pi]$ replaced by any set of non-zero Lebesgue measure on the unit circle by first noting that since $|f| \le M, \log |f| \le \log M$ so

$\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \le \pi \log M+\int_0^{\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta =-\infty$

Then since if we assume $f$ non-identical zero and $f(0)=0$ replacing $f(w)$ by $f(w)/w^n$ where $n \ge 1$ is the (finite) order of the zero of $f$ at $0$, nothing changes on the boundary as absolute values go ($|w|=1$!) there), we can assume $f(0) \ne 0$ so Jensen theorem shows that $\log |f(0)|+\sum_{|z_k|<r}\log(r/|z_k|)=1/2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta, z_k$ the (finitely many) roots of $f$ in $|z|<r<1$ so since $\log(r/|z_k|)>0, |z_k|<r$, we get

$2\pi \log |f(0)| \le \int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}(\log^+ |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta-\log^- |f(re^{i\theta})|)d\theta$  and using the boundness of $f$ we get:

$2\pi \log |f(0)| \le \int_0^{2\pi}-\log^- |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta +2\pi \log M$

Now we can apply Fatou's lemma and get:

$\liminf_{r \to 1}\int_0^{2\pi}\log^- |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \ge \int_0^{2\pi}\liminf_{r \to 1}\log^- |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\log^- |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta $ which gives:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \ge -\int_0^{2\pi}\log^-|f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \ge (\limsup_{r \to 1})\int_0^{2\pi}-\log^- |f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \ge 2\pi (\log |f(0)|-\log |M|) > -\infty$ so we get the required contradiction with $f$ (hence $G,H$) not identically zero and done!

Comment: Since as you claim, we can replace $[0,2\pi]$ by any poisitive Lebesgue measure, the result still holds if the limit of the integration in the question replaced by some $a\in [0,\infty), b\in (a,\infty]. $ Isn't it?

Comment: Also you mentioned that the result is classic for the unit disc version. Can you please say the name of the result or kindly attach a link of the result? Thank you.

Comment: this is a standard Hardy space result and the proof for bounded functions is as above (if instead of $[0,\pi]$ we have a set $A$ of non-zero measure use $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \le 2\pi \log M+\int_A log |f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$) -any book on Hardy spaces has this as one of the first results - I personally recommend Duren as an excellent starter but Rudin RC has some of this stuff in chapter 17

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: So the thing is if the limits of the integration in the question was $(-\infty,\infty)$ then the proof will be a lot easier. Isn't it sir?

Comment: for the full circle, the result follows directly from Fatou's lemma indeed

Comment: @Conard how can we say that $|f(z)|\leq M?$ we have that $F$ is bounded in each of the half plane. There is no uniform bound of $F$ on the upper half plane. Am I right or missing something?

Comment: Not sure about the question - if $f$ is bounded in $U$ and $f$ is bounded in $V$, then $f$ is bounded in $U \cup V$